# Singular points of $(4x^3 y^3 + 1/x)dx + (3x^4 y^2 - 1/y)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singularity

Consider the ODE
$$(4x^3 y^3 + 1/x)dx + (3x^4 y^2 - 1/y)dy = 0.$$

I can easily be shown that when $x\not =0$ and $y \not = 0$, this ODE is an exact DE, hence by doing the computation we get that any solution $y=y(x)$ satisfies
$$F(x,y) = x^4 y^3 + \ln|x/y| = c,$$
for some $c \in \mathbb{R}.$

**My question** is that since in order to for $F(x,y)$ to be defined we need $x \not = 0$ and $y \not = 0$, when we solve $F(x,y) = c$, are the values $x_0$ s.t $y(x_0) = 0$ also a singular point of this ODE ?  I mean I'm confused with the domain of the solutions in this particular ODE because by existance theorem, to have a solution, we need $y \not = 0$, but as can be seen in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651363/how-can-a-point-that-makes-the-ode-undefined-be-included-into-a-domain-of-any-so) question, there is the concept of "Analytic continuation" of the solution, so I don't know whether should I consider the point where $y = 0$ as in the solution or not.

Comment: Your equation is not even defined when one of the two variable is zero, so it simply does not make sense to look for solutions there.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez This is exactly the same thing what I have argues in here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651363/how-can-a-point-that-makes-the-ode-undefined-be-included-into-a-domain-of-any-so

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez But apparently, we do "extend" the domain of the solution in some cases for some reasons.

Comment: I don't know what that says, but since your equation makes no sense on the coordinate axes, it simply does not make to ask if it has solutions there. There are other, related equations (multiply yours by xy, for example) for which matters are different — but your equ, as you wrote it, does not make sense in the axes.