# For a solution to an ODE, when do we apply analytic continuation at a point where ODE is undefined?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, analytic-continuation

As a continuation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651363/how-can-a-point-that-makes-the-ode-undefined-be-included-into-a-domain-of-any-so) question, the given answer states that at a point where the ODE is undefined, we apply "analytic continuation" (if this is the correct terminology) to the solution so that the domain of the solution is extended to a point where the ODE is undefined.

However, as you can see the comments to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659906/singular-points-of-4x3-y3-1-xdx-3x4-y2-1-ydy-0) question, it is still not clear for me why are we doing this ? and when do we have to do this ? I mean as @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez pointed out the second question, that is linked, talking about solutions of an ODE at a point where the ODE is undefined does not make sense.However, as my professor stated earlier, we say that the ODE might have infinitely many solution at such a point, as it is the case in the first question that is linked.

Therefore my question is that when do extend the domain of a solution of an ODE, when do we have to, and when do not do that ?